# labeling points on an archetype archmap

Tags: r

How might one add labels to an archmap from the archetypes package?  Or alternatively, would it be possible to recreate the archmap output in ggplot?

Using code from the SportsAnalytics demo (I hope this isn't bad form)

```
library("SportsAnalytics")
library("archetypes")
data("NBAPlayerStatistics0910")

dat <- subset(NBAPlayerStatistics0910,
             select = c(Team, Name, Position,
                        TotalMinutesPlayed, FieldGoalsMade))

mat <- as.matrix(subset(dat, select = c(TotalMinutesPlayed, FieldGoalsMade)))
a3 <- archetypes(mat, 3)

archmap(a3)
```

I'd like the player names ( NBAPlayerStatistics0910$Name ) over the points on the chart.  Something like below but more readable.

[image: ggplot geom_text example]

Comment: posted a possible answer below, but with that many points on the visualization, I can't see any way you'll get a good text overlay. One other options is to make this interactive so a hover-over on a point would show the individual's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind tweaking things a bit, you can start with the `archmap()` function base, toss in an extra parameter and add a `text()` call:

```
amap2 <- function (object, a.names, projection = simplex_projection, projection_args = list(), 
          rotate = 0, cex = 1.5, col = 1, pch = 1, xlab = "", ylab = "", 
          axes = FALSE, asp = TRUE, ...) 
{
  stopifnot("archetypes" %in% class(object))
  stopifnot(is.function(projection))
  k <- object$k
  if (k < 3) {
    stop("Need at least 3 archetypes.\n")
  }
  cmds <- do.call(projection, c(list(parameters(object)), projection_args))
  if (rotate != 0) {
    a <- pi * rotate/180
    A <- matrix(c(cos(a), -sin(a), sin(a), cos(a)), ncol = 2)
    cmds <- cmds %*% A
  }
  hmds <- chull(cmds)
  active <- 1:k %in% hmds
  plot(cmds, type = "n", xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, axes = axes, 
       asp = asp, ...)
  points(coef(object) %*% cmds, col = col, pch = pch)

  ######################
  # PLAY WITH THIS BIT #
  ######################
  text(coef(object) %*% cmds, a.names, pos=4)
  ######################

  rad <- ceiling(log10(k)) + 1.5
  polygon(cmds[hmds, ])
  points(cmds[active, ], pch = 21, cex = rad * cex, bg = "grey")
  text(cmds[active, ], labels = (1:k)[active], cex = cex)
  if (any(!active)) {
    points(cmds[!active, , drop = FALSE], pch = 21, cex = rad * 
             cex, bg = "white", fg = "grey")
    text(cmds[!active, , drop = FALSE], labels = (1:k)[!active], 
         cex = cex, col = "grey20")
  }
  invisible(cmds)
}

amap2(a3, dat$Name)
```

Obviously, my completely quick stab is not the end result you're looking for, but it should help you get on your way (if I read what you want to do correctly).

[image: vis]

Comment: Awesome, this looks like it will work.  I'm getting an error on my real data set so I'll see if I can work through that.  Thanks for the help.